# Group a column when none of the rows are unique into one using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
Name Class Marks1 Marks2
AA    CC    10     
AA    CC           33
AA    CC    21     
AA    CC           24
```

I want to transform data in the above format into

```
Name Class Marks1  Marks2
AA   CC    10      33
AA   CC    21      24
```

How should i achieve the result?
PS- This is just an example of the data the data is too big and has many more columns and it can have many such rows. How should i remove the duplicate rows without affecting the data quality.

Comment: Set the index to the Class column first, then use groupby

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
In [421]: df.groupby(df.index // 2).first()
Out[421]:
  Name Class  Marks1  Marks2
0   AA    CC    10.0    33.0
1   AA    CC    21.0    24.0
```

Comment: Might want to use `np.arange` (or similar) just in case `df.index` isn't compatible with this approach.